# Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)

Tags: android-emulator, intel, virtualization, haxm

I have an issue with my HAXM installation. Here is the thing. I got this error every single time I tried to install HAXM for my computer:
[image: Installation error print-screen]

Problem is, that my computer supports Virtualization Technology (see pic below). Any idea how to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: During installation, how much memory do I use ? I have 4GB and it is suggesting 1gb

Comment: Do you use Avast? If you do, try to disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again. Work for me!

Comment: If HAXM doesn't ask how much memory you want to give it and immediately gives the above error message, @Ajay has the solution you are looking for.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration
c:\Users\janedoe\AppData\Local\Android> sdk\emulator\emulator -accel-check helped me to find that it is already installed

Comment: this link has the working answer in my case: https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/105

Comment: [@Madushan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676171/14774610)
<strong>step 6</strong> did it for me!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Just follows these steps:

1. Go to *Control Panel → Program and Feature*.
2. Click on *Turn Window Features on and off*. A window opens.
3. Uncheck *Hyper-V* and *Windows Hypervisor Platform* options and restart your system.

Now, you can Start HAXM installation without any error.

Comment: This was the one that worked for me and a couple of my buddies that had the same problem, should be top answer.

Comment: @Dave: Always Welcome :)

Comment: What if I can't uncheck this option because I don't have? Can't use HAXM until I change my laptop?

Comment: What do you mean by I don't have ? First , you check weather your laptop support Intel Virtualization technique or not ? As you seen above in second screen shot in question that Inter Virtualization Technology is 'YES'. What is it in your scenario ?

Comment: Thanks that was it for me, I don't even user Hyper-V, shame both can't be used (I may one day make a windows Phone App)

Comment: I guess, Hyper-V option is only available in Windows 8 and higher versions. How can solve this in Windows 7?

Comment: No, Hyper-V is not depend on windows, I think, it depend on your motherboard. your motherboard may have or not support Hyper-V option.

Comment: I have Hyper-V already unchecked but still getting same error.. What is next option remaining

Comment: Check once also in BIOS settings, and it may be possibility that your antivirus stop you to use Hyper-v. So, once deactivate or stop your antivirus and then try again the above steps.

Comment: I followed your steps...After crossing 2nd step.,I have not found Hyper-V in my system...What do I have to do? @AjaySharma

Comment: @ParamaSudha if that option is not available, it means that your CPU not support this technology. It's my assumption. Don't go and buy new CPU on the basis of my comments :P

Comment: Then, I can not use AVD in my Android Studio.Isn't it?

Comment: You may use ARM system images for create Android AVD.

Comment: @ParamaSudha - Yesterday, my friend bought a new laptop. When he go to above settings that Hyper-V option was not their but when I check his laptop system info it shows that his system support Hyper-V. So the conclusion is that if Hyper-V connection is not showing in Program and Feature , it doesn't means that your System not supported Hyper-V. Their are lots of other way to check that. Such as Intel Processor Identify Utility Software or Write command in cmd Systeminfo.exe

Comment: Just FYI if anyone is struggling after disabling hyper-v and rebooting, this only worked for me after a 2nd reboot. I did run into some pending windows updates, possibly not a coincidence.

Comment: @AjaySharma, In my system there is no any option like `Hyper-V option`

Comment: If you own an AMD machine then also you will face similar issue and to enable virtualization in AMD processor its bit more complicated  and there is a different approach. So make sure whether you are using AMD or Intel machine

Comment: ok, but what if I'm actively USING the hyperv functionality in Windows?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Answer (score 47):

Hello and welcome to the 3rd installment of the infamous Android Emulator on Windows saga. Despite the combined 3 trillion dollar market cap of Microsoft and Google, this remains to be a problem harder than going to the moon.

Below is the somewhat comprehensive list for Windows (so far as of circa 11/2022)

---

First make sure you have the latest version of Windows. As of writing, this is Windows 11 22H2 with all updates installed. If you have an older version of Windows, you'll have to try each one of the below, with possibly different combinations. Otherwise follow from the top until your issue is solved. It is ordered from the easiest/most likely culprit on a decent Windows machine, to the most unlikely cause.

Note that if you're doing below on a corporate machine, some of the below actions may be blocked by your admin, and/or flag your machine as suspicious activity as some actions intentionally turns off some security features. Depending on your situation, you may want to give a heads-up to your IT/security team.

**If your Windows device has Bitlocker enabled on your boot drive** contact your IT admin first. Messing with virtualization and boot configuration may trigger bitlocker prompts upon reboot. If you're working from home,this may mean taking your laptop to the office to get it unlocked by IT, as Windows may refuse to boot without unlocking BitLocker.

---

To find what is blocking the emulator launch, the surefire way is to open a terminal (cmd or powershell) and launch to from there as below.

First kill any existing emulator.exe instances, adb.exe instances, java.exe instances, qemu instances, android studio instances. Check in task manager to be sure.

The adb relaunches itself so its ok be running. But make sure android studio is not running. It seems to lock files/cache and not flush emulator configs, that may crash the emulator at launch, without any useful logs.

in a terminal

- `cd your_sdk_location\emulator`
- `emulator.exe -list-avds`
- this will list what AVDs you have. Find the one you want
- `emulator.exe -avd your_avd_name -verbose`

This will have a long log, and will have some information on what the failure is. If you see a VM heap size being outside of limits, it may say that it it automatically set to lowest or highest value. **This is a lie**. Open emulator settings and set it to within the limits manually, usually 550MB works. Launch android studio and edit the emulator instance to be within this limit, then close android studio, then wait about 30 seconds before attempting to launch the emulator. For all attempts of launching the emulator below, do not rely on android studio, launch from command line instead.

Note that the emulator editor UI in android studio can corrupt the config at times. If this happens, I don't know where this is stored, so you may have to delete and re-create the AVD. If this doesn't work, do not change and configs during AVD creation, then launch it from command line.

If the emulator doesn't launch, no useful failure logs, yet the emulator.exe exits after a few minutes, you may have android studio running. Exit/Kill Android studio, wait a minute or so and try again. If still fails, reboot.

---

1. **Have an Antivirus (other than Microsoft Defender)?**

   - Disable it
   - Reboot and try to launch the emulator
2. **Disable Hypervisor Boot**

   - open an admin terminal (cmd or powershell)
   - run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
   - try to launch the emulator. If still broken, try rebooting.
3. **If your failure is due to install of [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/latest)/[AMD hypervisor driver](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors) failing**

   - run `systeminfo` in a terminal
   - at the end under `Hyper-V Requirements:` if it says  `A hypervisor has been detected` this means emulator cannot launch virtualization.
   - Open Start > Windows Security > Device Security > Core isolation
   - turn off Core Isolation (previously known as Memory Integrity/Isolated User Mode)
   - Open `Turn Windows features on or off` and disable

     - Hyper-V Platform
     - Hyper-V Management Tools
     - Windows Hypervisor Platform
   - You can enable them after HAXM/AMD Driver install
   - on an admin prompt run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
   - reboot
   - try to launch the emulator
4. **Check BIOS**

   - go into BIOS/UEFI setup and look for settings like

     - VT-x
     - VT-d
     - Virtualization Technology
     - Hardware Virtualization
   - Make sure these settings are enabled
   - try to launch the emulator
5. **Uninstall Docker Desktop**

   - Some users have reported that uninstalling Docker Desktop fixed their issue.
   - It is unclear as to why docker desktop interferes with haxm installation. The reason is probably that it supports running docker images via a Hyper-V backend, and disabling this feature does not remove the hypervisor completely.
   - Go to Settings -> Add or remove programs, and uninstall docker desktop
   - reboot
   - try to launch the emulator
6. **Nothing works**

   - You shouldn't get here, since Android emulator can now run alongside with Hyper-V if you have 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' enabled.
   - If nothing above works, as a last resort you can try running [Android in a Hyper-V](http://techgenix.com/running-an-android-emulator-on-hyper-v/) VM and get ADB to connect to it. (Not a solution, but a workaround)
   - You can also run android using a third-party emulator like [Genimotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).
7. **¯\*(ツ)*/¯**

   - [Debug on a physical device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)

     - You can also use Wifi debugging via `adb pair ip:port` and `adb connect ip:port` commands.
   - or [get a Macbook](https://www.apple.com/mac/)

Comment: Step 6 did it for me! New Dell XPS15

Comment: The sixth step helped me too! Laptop: Asus N550JK, Windows 10 Pro, Build 19018 (Insider Program).

Comment: My PC processor is AMD Ryzen 5 and I did all things from above steps. But still I cannot install HXAM in Android Studio. Please help me.

Comment: In addition to this answer; if you memory integration toggle automatically turns on after reboot even when you turned off; turn the "Secure Boot" to disabled in your BIOS settings.

Comment: It seems if "Virtual Machine Platform" is enabled in Windows Features also , you will not be able to install HAXM. Disabling "Virtual Machine Platform" fixed it for me. I enabled it for WSL.

Comment: step 6 winds the internet

Answer (score 30):

After few days of googling I found, that problem was caused by hyperthreading (or hyper - v). I decided to edit my boot.ini file with option to start up windows with hyperthreading turned off.
I followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/04/14/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry.aspx) and now everything works perfect

Comment: This did it for me:
"dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V"

Comment: Yeah, this basically means I can't do windows phone development alongside android development on the same laptop since you need Hyper-V for WP emulators. This smells fishy...

Comment: The problem is on Microsoft's side. You are right to say something smells fishy but if it is intentional, Microsoft is just slow at updating the HyperV virtualization layer that is supposed to detect the processor capabilities and expose the Intel-VT features to whatever OS is residing above Hyper-V.

Comment: I just enabled the virtualization option on BIOS when starting windows, and worked.

Comment: [Hyper**threading**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is something entirely unrelated to Windows' Hyper-V hyper*visor* using Intel VT-x or AMD-V hardware virtualization features.

Answer (score 16):

chances are that you have windows 8 with hyper-v installed? if yes remove hyper-v and your problem goes away!

Answer (score 11):

1. First of all make sure you enabled Virtualization Technology in your BIOS. After restarting your computer press F1-F12 on your keyboard and find this option.
2. Make sure you disabled Hyper-V in your Windows 7/Windows 8. You can turn it off in Control Panel -> Programs -> Windows functions
3. You can try to disable your antivirus program for the whole installation process. Remember to restore all antivirus services after installing HAXM.
4. Some people recommend *cold boot* which is:

   1. Disabling Virtualization in your BIOS
   2. Restart computer and turn it off
   3. Enable VT in your BIOS
   4. Restart computer, turn it off
   5. It's likely that now might be allowed to install HAXM

Unfortunately this step didn't work for me

1. Last but not least: try this workaround patch released by Intel.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown

All you have to do is to download the package, unzip it, put it together with HAXM installator file and run .cmd file included in the package - remember, start it as an Administrator.

I had a lot of problems with installing HAXM and only the last step helped me.

Comment: No problem! I was googling the solution very long and after I found it, I decided to share it on stackoverflow. This workaround patch is a key solution to be honest.

Comment: I think the script does not work if there are spaces in the path of `intelhaxm.exe`. Example: I use Android Studio and the file is stored under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Man‌​ager`, then I need to copy it to somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

In the "Turn Windows features on or off" window, un-check Hyper-V and also ensure that Windows Hypervisor Platform is unchecked. Windows Hypervisor Platform being enabled can also block the installation of the Intel HaxM

[image: Features to be disabled]

Comment: There is no Hyper-V in my Computer, Do I have to change my computer now :/

Comment: After an hour of struggling, the _Windows Hypervisor Platform_ is what blocked the installation. Didn't realize there were two of them!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe VT-X is not enabled in your BIOS.

See Intel HAXM documentation here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

> **Intel VT-x not enabled**
>
> In some cases, Intel VT-x may be disabled in the system BIOS and must
>   be enabled within the BIOS setup utility. To access the BIOS setup
>   utility, a key must be pressed during the computer’s boot sequence.
>   This key is dependent on which BIOS is used but it is typically the
>   F2, Delete, or Esc key. Within the BIOS setup utility, Intel VT may be
>   identified by the terms "VT", "Virtualization Technology", or "VT-d."
>   Make sure to enable all of the Virtualization features.

Answer (score 4):

Anti-virus software may interfere with the HAXM installation.
After trying to figure out what went wrong for a few hours I found a strange solution - uninstalling my anti-virus software , installing HAXM (which worked) and then re-installing the anti-virus software (Avast in my case but it could happen with other anti-virus programs as well.

The full check I went through to get this running is:

1. Check the 'Virtualization' and vt-X feature in the BIOS.
2. Verifying Hyper-V is not installed.
3. Checking weather vt-X is enabled in windows with the Intel tool and  MS tool (mentioned in previous posts in this thread).
4. Disabling the anti-virus which didn't help.
5. Uninstalling the anti-virus (which solved the problem for me).

Comment: The feature in Avast that causes this problem can be disabled, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10, Windows Defender has a feature of core isolation which uses virtualisation technology that will also interupt in working of HAXM. Disable it and try again. In my case disabling it solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an AMD Ryzen processor in your computer you need the following setup requirements to be in place:

1. AMD Processor - Recommended: AMD® Ryzen™ processors
2. Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher - download via Android Studio
   Preview page
3. Android Emulator v27.3.8+ - download via Android Studio SDK Manager
4. x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD) - Create AVD
5. Windows 10 with April 2018 Update
6. Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

**Note:There is Hyper-V features... You should enable Windows Hypervisor Platform not Hyper-V. 
Windows Hypervisor Platform is at the bottom**

After conditions done avd x86 work without haxm install

[Reference](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html)

Comment: Ryzen 2700X here and was going mad because Hyper V disabled and VT-x enabled... this worked.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In many cases some antivirus also start HyperV with window start and does not allow HAXM to install.
I faced this issue because of AVAST antivirus.
So I uninstalled AVAST, then HAXM installed properly after restart.
Then I re-installed AVAST.

So its just a check while installing  as now even with AVAST installed back,  HAXM works properly with virtual box and android emulators.

Answer (score 1):

After I installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, Visual Studio notified me about a Windows Phone emulator update, which I installed (it was really a new component, not an update). It turned out this enabled Hyper-V, which broke HAXM.

The solution was to uninstall the emulator from Programs and Features and to turn off Hyper-V from Windows Features (search for "Windows Features" and click "Turn Windows features on or off").

Answer (score 1):

If you dont find Hyper-V option in control panel as said in other [responses here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839301/3214497), try entering BIOS setup (restarting and pressing F-12 or ESC or other depending on your PC) and enabling Virtualization, located probably in CPU options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows 10 and had this problem after I changed my SSD, I fixed it by disabling the VT support on Bios. I got a different error after I ran the installer. I rebooted and enabled VT support again and voila, working now.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the answers doesn't work just remove **Android Emulator** and reinstall it again. and after that try installing **Intel Haxm**.

Answer (score 0):

**If none of the answers worked out for you, try this,**

Hyper-V might not be disabled
If you have windows 10 features such as Device Guard and Credential Guard is enabled, it can prevent Hyper-V from being completely disabled.

The Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool released by Microsoft can disable the said Windows 10 features along with Hyper-V:

Download it here, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337

Download the latest version of the Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool.
Unzip
Open the Command Prompt using Run as administrator
@powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "X:\path\to\dgreadiness_v3.6\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable"
Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I already tried all of the possible solutions on stackoverflow and didn't work
What I tried:

1. Disable Hyper-V in windows feature
2. Disable Hyper-V with command
3. Disable Device Guard
4. etc etc
   Above solution still give me information about Hyper-V in System Information and the HAXM still failed to install.

But finally I found the solution, you have to **disable Hyper-V from System Configuration**:

1. Open System Configuration
2. Click Service tab
3. Uncheck all of Hyper-V related

Check System Information then Hyper-V is off now

Answer (score 0):

Fix the error. follow the following steps

1. Turn off Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform
2. Goto RegEdit "Windows Defender is blocking HAXM."

   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard
   - Set the key EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity to '0'

**if Key is not available create a key**

3. Re-boot the machine
4. Install the intelhaxm-android.exe

Comment: That worked perfectly for my case, I couldn't install the "Intel Haxm" on my machine in any way!