# android studio: unable to turn on the emulator

Tags: android-studio

The error I get is:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I believe it is asked once per week and I have search for different solution but still fail
In the installation, I get the same message as the first image of the follow post.
[Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

The solution I have tried:
1. disable and enable the VT in the bios----same problem in installation of Intel haxm
2. disable the Hyper-V ---------------------Seem my windows do not conation Hyper-V
3. download the workaround patch released by Intel in
http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown
whew execute the .cmd file, it just jump up the cmd for half an second and not thing is happened.

In my process, I have stop my avast anti-virus, and I am using windows 8.1.

Could anyone help?

Comment: what CPU do you have?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4712MQ CPU @ 2.30GHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things you haven't tried : 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn    (to make sure XD bit is on)
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
  (and reboot)