# Intel HAXM for Android on Surface Pro3

Tags: android

I am brand new to Android development.

I have installed Android Studio, but the emulator fails to run claiming that intel HAXM is not installed.
The thing is it is installed because when I run the SDK Manager, it tells me it is installed.
I checked online and someone says it only works on machines that support intel virtualization.
I am working on a Surface Pro3 and I have my Windows Phone emulators running in hyper-V and, so I know that virtualization is enabled.

What can I do?
Is there a specific kind of virtualization that is required?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, sometimes your windows machine will tell you it is enabled but it's not or it at least isn't recognized by Android Studio / HAXM / emulator.

There is a post here you can give a look: [Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

One suggestion is to disable it.

Alternatively you can run the emulator as an ARM instead of intel based.

Answer (score 0):

I have a surface pro 2 and Win 10 64 bit. Had to go to "Turn Windows Features on or Off" in Control panel and disbale/uncheck both Hyper-V as well as Windows Hypervisor (this feature is only in 64 bit).

Restart and then try installing IntelHaxm again. You can find that where you SDK is installed. sdklocation\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager.

You can check you sdk location in Android Studio System Settings > Android SDK.