# Android Development: Error in AVD Emulator

Tags: java, android, mobile, compiler-errors

"Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!"

I can't use a virtual device because of this. Yes, I installed the Accelerator from the Manager and even went into my app data and ran the intelhax.exe program, but there I found ANOTHER error telling me that my computer couldn't handle something about Intel.

I need help with this, and I can't start making apps until I get passed this block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Android SDK Manager and download HAXM package from Extras

Comment: I did download it from the Android SDK Manager and I even opened it. I got this error:

Comment: "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x), HAXM cannot be installed. Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information."

Comment: check this old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat

Answer (score 0):

In order to use HAXM (including the x86 targets) you will need to have the additional functionality available from a product that only runs on Intel processors.  You must have an Intel processor in your computer, then will need to install additional tools (including a driver) on your machine.

Your first problem was not having the additional drivers installed, your second problem, is that you can't install them because you don't have a compatible Intel processor.

You don't need to use HAXM to run the emulator (although it IS much faster).  When creating a new AVD, target the "arm" system images, instead of the "x86" ones.

Another alternative is to download and use the Genymotion product which is a 3rd party emulator, and works well.