# Problems starting Android emulator for Windows 8

Tags: android, emulation, intel, haxm

I'm having problems starting my Android Emulator to test code I have written in Android Studio. The emulator starts but does not open it just continues to load for what seems like forever. I have tried installing HAXM on my laptop after doing some research thinking this would make the emulator load faster but when I try to run the installer on my computer I get an error message. It says "This computer does not support Intel Virtulization Technology (VT-x). HAXM Cannot be installed. Please refer to Intel HAXM for more information." I'm not sure if this means that I can't install HAXM on my laptop at all or if I need to adjust the settings to be able to. Any type of advice on this would be helpful because this is really slowing down my development process.

Comment: First search before making a question.
[Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built in emulator for Android Studio, many other people have found it to be slow.  This was the case when I started using Android Studio a few versions back.  I'm not sure whether the default emulator has improved since then.

Most Android developers are using the Genymotion emulator (www.Genymotion.com) and/or actual phones and tablets that they plug in via USB.

Comment: Thanks joshgoldeneagle I have GenyMotion installed on my laptop now and it's emulator is running perfectly fine. I've heard about it before but never thought to look into it until I switched laptops and had the problems with the default emulator.

Comment: Glad I could help, plz upvote as useful answer if that is the case, or mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether your processor (must be Intel) support VT at ark.intel.com and type in the model number of your processor.