# Intel HAXM installation errors : (AVD unable to start, does not support (VT-x) and Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown )

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

When i tried to install HAXM manually it shows an error message : "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)"

[image]

: I tried some suggestions from here

1. [Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

   2. Tried to "on-off" windows features but get following error:

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown. A Windows feature name was not recognized. Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and tr y the command again.

[image]

Please help,
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the CPU doesn't support VT-x.
There are CPUs that don't :-/ Check the following list:

http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology

Comment: Thank you...  but avd from eclips is running this problem occured only in androi studio.

Comment: don't get it. the error you showed was from haxm installation program. it's not AS nor Eclipse...