# Android Studio, emulator, HAXM, VT-x not working

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, haxm

I am trying to use the Android Studio emulator on Windows 10.  I can't install the HAXM in the SDK folder because VT-x is not enabled.  I tried disabling the Secure Boot Control in the UEFI Firmware Settings.  I also tried turning off Hyper-V off in Windows Features on/off.  I also tried turning off the hardware visualization setting in Avast.  None of these are working and I am still unable to install HAXM.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat

Answer (score 1):

I have enabled virtualisation technology (Hyper-V does not exist in my windows 7) but without any success. what worked for me is installing [v7.4.1](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.4.1) instead of the latest version v7.5.2 (at the time I am writing this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Even after enabling the VT in BIOS, Android studio wouldn't detect it. The solution that worked for me was to do a cold reboot (power off the PC completely, i.e. when you restart it after you change BIOS setting for VT, shut it down again, unplug it from the mains to power off the motherboard and power on again after 10 secs. For laptops, I guess you'd need to take off the battery and plug it back).
I have Asus MB.