# I cannot open AVD in android studio

Tags: android, device, virtual, android-virtual-device

i cannot open AVD in android studio, firstly it gave me error as NX is disable in bios and i enabled it. Now it is showing me as VT-x is disabled, enable it, Please help in this errors!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Comment: You need to provide more information. os, etc

Answer (score 0):

Simple.. Follow this link 
[link 1 Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Cv2Hj2PlQE)

and this one
[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913121/android-studio-emulator-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Open your BIOS setting enabled the Virtualization(VT) in BIOS settings

some antivirus options also prevent HAXM installation.
For example: In Avast antivirus under Settings (parametres) tab > Troubleshooting , you should uncheck "Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization" & "Enable avast self-defense module".

Control Panel -> "Programs" -> "Turn Windows features on or off" (under "Programs and Features") and locate "Hyper-V", uncheck, reboot.

Important
Go to MyPC / right click / Advanced System Settings / Advanced / In Performance click SETTINGS / Data Execution Prevention and enable DEP for all programs and services.

> for kvm

Use the below command to check whether the KVM is installed in the machine or not,

kvm-ok 
Output:

INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
Output like the below means,

INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
In this scenario need to install KVM using the below command,

sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils

Comment: I enabled that all sir but a dialog box is welcomed when i opened AVD like this: "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. /dev/kvm is not found. EnableVT-x in your bios security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module". I cannot understand that at all, please help me to work AVD.

Comment: @ShivAVidEoSTuBe have u enabled virtualization in your bios

Comment: Yes sir i enabled it.

Comment: I cannot understand the commands you provided, and when i typed commands in cmd it is giving me as not recognizable command, and i think you gave me commands for Linux. Am using windows 7 ultimate. Thank you, please give me advise.