# Running Android emulator on intel machine

Tags: android, windows, windows-7, emulation, intel

I am trying to run emulator in Android studio.

It gave me error that "requires hardware acceleration".
so I did some research, and found that I need `HAXM installer` installed. source can be found out here [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

So I downloaded it. I ran again and then it gave error "This computer does not support VT-x" so called `Virtualization Technology`.

So in the same above posting I found out I need to enable VT from bios settings. I did that too. But when I try to install HAXM it again giving me error "This computer does not support VT-x"

How I can install HAXM and eventually able to run android emulator?

**Updated** I have tried [Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

When I opened turn feature on or off, its not giving me Hyper-V option.

Thnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: @petey I have updated my question

Comment: @codecats intel(R) 2 GHz

Comment: @codecats Intel (R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU T6400 2.00 GHz

Comment: Sorry @Alex,  that Intel (R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU T6400 2.00 GHz proc doesnt support vt-x,  http://ark.intel.com/products/40479/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: You can run emulator using ARM machine, do you have any specific reason so that you need only intel machine.

Comment: @Keshav1234 I have intel machine. The other one I dont have

Comment: @Alex I didnt understand while creating AVD you can select either intel or ARM right? only thing is you should have arm image installed fro sdk manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That CPU (from early 2009) does not support virtualization, so you will need to use a software enhancer - like genymotion.

Comment: can u add a few lines explaining what is genymotion?

Comment: It's just one of many android software emulators (Intel haxm is a hardware based emulator, explaining it's fast speed). http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/run-android-apps-on-pc  lists/compares several software emulators