# Error in Launching Android Virtual Device(AVD)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

**I tried to create an emulator(AVD) for test my app.When I tried I got this window.** [image]

**After referred some other webpage I use the following path to install HAX-M**
**D:\MYSDKLOCATION\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android**

**But got the next error. Please help me to create AVD.**
[image]

**UPDATE**

**Even I followed all the steps of this link [STACKOVERFLOW LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat/27839301?noredirect=1#comment57891287_27839301).But couldnt solve the above bug. Still I have not found Hyper-V in my system...What do I have to do?**

Please help me..Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't as haxm is not supported

Comment: working on windows 8??

Comment: Your system not supported haxm

Comment: Is it possible to make it supported?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat  check this link

Comment: You can start virtualization from bios settings

Comment: check this link and letme know is it helpful or not

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek for the link.

Comment: Okay I will check @Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Try to use USB Debugging instead of using emulator For USB Debugging follow this link

```
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
```

or try with this video link:  `https://youtu.be/Ucs34BkfPB0`

Comment: Ya...I am using this.But I m moving to next.Need to test android watchface app in AVD.

Answer (score 0):

VTx might be disabled in bios. 
Check it.

I am not windows user but [it seems to fix in windows8](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/)