# HAXM setup failed in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an error saying installation did not complete successfully,see IDE log for Errors. When i saw, it said "Failed to update status to COMPLETE: HAXM setup failed!". Please can anyone tell me what is wrong

```css
Failed to update status to COMPLETE: HAXM setup failed!
com.android.repository.api.PackageOperation$StatusChangeListenerException: HAXM setup failed!
 at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.install.HaxmInstallListener.statusChanged(HaxmInstallListener.java:57)
 at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.updateStatus(AbstractPackageOperation.java:450)
 at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.complete(AbstractPackageOperation.java:176)
 at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.completePackages(InstallTask.java:151)
 at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:107)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following link to install the Intel HAXM manually from Intel site. You may have to disable Hyper-V in Windows Features.

[Installation Instructions for Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) - Microsoft Windows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If any answers from SO didn't help you (e.g. manual installation HAXM, checking Hyper-V options etc.) and you are a Windows user:

1. try to install/update Visual C++ Redistributable,
2. try to install HAXM via IDE again.

Answer (score 0):

HAXM setup can fail due to many many reasons.

Try the list I put [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676171/975887). Unfortunately the errors don't say much about the root cause.