# Can not install IntelHAXM

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.3

I had tried many times but I still can not solve my problem.

Tried through these steps:

1. I have enabled virtualization in BIOS setup,
2. and disabled *Windows Defender*, but still can not install *IntelHAXM*,
3. and I have disabled Hyper-V through Commandprompt.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What version of Windows are you on? What exact error are you getting, and in what stage of the installation process are you getting this error?

Comment: i am using window 10 pro,

Comment: https://imgur.com/mpdPMj0 and this show error while installing intelHAXM

Comment: and in sdk tools it is install -https://imgur.com/LGxDmPu

Comment: and here is my system configuration setting which shows which function is allowed-https://imgur.com/SeOtaUn

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have? If you have tried everything listed in this related thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat) it's possible your computer simply may not support HAXM.