# android Intel haxm bug

Tags: android, android-emulator, intel, haxm

I have installed android studio and in order to use emulators on my pc I did try to install **intel HAXM**. It prompted for error due to lack of **intel vt-x** support and I tried to enabled this options with many tricks which explained in detail [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1366264/vt-x-not-available-on-i5-6400-cpu-w-windows-10-pro-64-bit?noredirect=1#comment2054925_1366264). After many changes, intel processor identification utility which was installed on my windows 10 pro, reported that intel vt-x is enabled on my pc and also a utility called **haxm_check.exe** reported that intel vt-x and nx is enabled on my pc. but when i tried to install **intelhaxm-android.exe** version 7.0.3 it prompted that **vt-x** or **nx** is missing and rolled back the setup.
Can somebody figure out what is wrong or how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

List of things to check is much larger for this issue. 
Also posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676171/975887 likely after you checked it.

Below is the full list for Windows (so far as of circa 12/2018)

1. **Check BIOS**

   - go into BIOS/UEFI setup and look for settings like VT-x, VT-d, Virtualization Technology, Hardware Virtualization and make sure it is **Enabled**. If the option is not there, check with your manufacturer and model to make sure it is supported.
2. **Disable Hyper-V**

   - Type 'windows features' into start menu, select 'Turn Windows Features On or Off'.
   - Unselect all Hyper-V related options, press OK, Reboot.
   - This will break any Hyper-V VMs you have, including any Windows Phone emulators and anything else you have setup that requires Hyper-V
   - Reboot Required
   - on an admin command prompt, run `systeminfo`. If it shows 'hypervisor is detected' under Hyper-V requirements, even after removing Hyper-V feature, you may have 'Core Isolation' enabled. See below on how to disable it.
   - As another option, try enabling '**Windows Hypervisor Platform**' if you still want your Hyper-V support. [More info here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/)
3. **AMD Ryzen ?**

   - If your CPU is AMD Ryzen, you may need to **enable** '*Windows Hypervisor Platform*' feature just like you disabled Hyper-V above.
   - If it is enabled and still things don't work, try disabling it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
   - Reboot required
4. **Disable Antivirus**

   - Try disabling your antivirus.
   - AVAST! and a few others interfere with the detection of virtualization. You can enable them after.
   - AVAST and some others also has some options that uses virtualization based isolation. Either disable them or temporally uninstall your AV.
5. **Disable Core Isolation**

   - Clean installs of Windows 10 1803 enables Core Isolation by default, which runs secure processes inside a virtualized container for security. This interferes with the detection of virtualization.
   - Machines that upgraded from an earlier version have this disabled, but check anyway.
   - Go to Windows Defender Security Center
   - Device Security > Core Isolation > details
   - **Disable** Memory Integrity
   - Reboot
6. **Disable hypervisor launch at boot**

   - on an admin command prompt, run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
   - reboot
   - to revert run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and reboot
7. **Nothing works**

   - You shouldn't get here, since Android emulator can now run alongside with Hyper-V if you have 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' is enabled.
   - If nothing above works, as a last resort you can try running [Android in a Hyper-V](http://techgenix.com/running-an-android-emulator-on-hyper-v/) VM and get ADB to connect to it. (Not a solution, but a workaround)
   - You can also run android using a third-party emulator like [Genimotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).
8. **¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

   - [Debug on a physical device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)