# Android Studio - Error x86 Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v, haxm

I am trying to setup Android Studio to develop a simple android application, and when I try to run the application I am returned this error. I have already enabled Hardware Acceleration in the BIOS and when I try to install the Hardware Accelerator(HAXM Installer) it fails to install, telling me that my computer does not support Hyper Virtualization Technology or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. I have tried to find Hyper-V on my laptop to uninstall it, however I don't even have this. 
I would appreciate help in setting up my emulator in Android Studio and fixing this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

Comment: What your operating system and version?