# Android emulator fails to start in windows 10 with exit code -805306369

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to just get the emulator installed and running (Android Studio 3.5 on Windows 10, i7 processor and 16GB RAM).

I finally got HAXM installed after following instructions from two blogs and three Stack Overflow questions and rebooting several times (eg [Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)).
edit: I switched on virtualization in the bios and disabled hypervisor.

However when I try to launch the emulator it just blacks out a portion of the screen and then does nothing else, it hasnt drawn anything to the screen (no window frame, buttons or content) and will stay like that indefinitely.  At this point the qemu process is using 40-70% of the CPU. 
The mouse displays the wait cursor if you hover over the blacked out portion of the screen, but if you click on it, it turns white and a dialog pops up saying

> qemu-system-x86_64.exe is not responding If you close the program, you
>   might lose information.

and it can then be closed resulting in this message in the event log:

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

I have tried a few different AVDs the most recent based on the Pixel device definition with the system image listed as Q, API 29, x86_64, Android 10.0 (Google Play). I fiddled with various parameters such as the camera settings and amount of memory, all to no avail.

I also reinstalled Android studio and HAXM :-(

Any ideas or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated, the only work-around I have at this stage is to use an actual device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to **enable virtualization** from boot menu if you've yet.

Comment: My system is a notebook with an external display plugged in and extending the desktop.  I have discovered now that if the AVD manager is on the notebooks screen it works but hangs as decribed if launched on the external display or even dragged there after it is launched.

Comment: May be you've got no juice to run AVD on notebook due to graphics processor limit.